# Ag Grid header component not found

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

Using Vue and just want to have a custom checkbox on a column header (just one header, not all of them). Don't need to implement sorting or any crazy behaviour on this column.

My main component that has AgGrid on it is really big, so the `...` below are just where other lines of code would normally be. This is just to show that I've imported the file and added it to components. This is the exact same way I import and call various `cellRendererFrameworks`.
On my main AgGrid component:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue'
  ...
  import AgGridSelectionHeader from '@/components/agGrid/AgGridSelectionHeader'

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'agGridInventoryView',
    components: {
      AgGridVue,
      ...
      AgGridSelectionHeader,
    },
    props: [...],
    data() {
      return {
        ...
        gridOptions: {
          rowSelection: 'multiple',
          rowModelType: 'serverSide',
          suppressRowClickSelection: true,
          cacheBlockSize: 20,
          cacheOverflowSize: 20,
          rowHeight: 59,
          serverSideSortingAlwaysResets: true,
          masterDetail: true,
          rowClassRules: {},
          suppressContextMenu: true,
          defaultColDef: {
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
          },
          columnTypes: {
            ...
            groupColumn: {
              cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
              headerComponent: AgGridSelectionHeader,
              headerComponentParams: {},
              checkboxSelection: true,
              width: 65,
              maxWidth: 65,
              minWidth: 65,
              menuTabs: [],
              sortable: false,
              resizable: false,
              pinned: 'left',
              lockPosition: true,
              lockVisible: true,
              lockPinned: true,
            },
          },
        },
        gridColumnDefs: [
          { headerName: '', field: 'type', type: 'groupColumn' },
          ...
```

My `headerComponent`. It's worth noting that even if I remove the empty lifecycle methods (so that the component really just has `template` and `name`) the error is still there.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'agGridSelectionHeader',
    components: { },
    props: [],
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    beforeMount() {

    },
    computed: {

    },
  })
</script>

<template lang="pug">
    span test
</template>
```

The error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and time again I'm seeing the flaws of the AgGrid documentation. Under React and Angular header component information it suggests using `headerComponentFramework`. Under Vue, it uses `frameworkComponents: {}` and `headerComponent`.

If you're using string names for your components, use `headerComponent`. If you're using direct references like I am, use `headerComponentFramework`. This applies to Vue as well as React and Angular.

Frustrating.

Comment: Thanks a lot , you saved a lot of time for me... !! you are right it is really frustrating.